# How to find numbers which GCD equal to 1 and those numbers are less than given in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to write code which gives you numbers which are less than given or entered number , and their GCD equal to 1 .  I wrote this code but I don't know if works or why not . For example I chose number 6. array will be like [1,2,3,4,5]. And my point is to filter numbers that GCD equals to 1. So it will be [1,5]. And their amount is two.

`a` is input number and `b` is list numbers that are less than entered one and not equal to zero . And then print it .

```
a = int(input("enter number \n"))
b = list(range(1,a))
print (b)
```

Then I convert list to array

```
for i in range(1, len(b)):
        b[i] = int(b[i])
```

and then this

```
        r = a % b[i]

        q = int ( a / b[i])

        while(r!=0):
            
            a = b[i]

            b[i] = r

            q = int ( a / b[i])

            r = a - (b[i] * q)


            print ( a , b[i], r )
            break
```

I am beginner .

Comment: How do you not know if it works. Have you tested it on some inputs and did it yield the expected results?

Comment: Yes I tested it and I think I did not get results what I wanted that's why posted here.

Comment: `for i in range(1, len(b)): b[i] = int(b[i])` is wrong for two reasons. 1) It has no effect, as `b` is already a list of integers. 2) Lists are 0-indexed, so a correct iterations on every element of `b` would be `for i in range(0, len(b)): ` or simply `for i in range(len(b)):`

Comment: "So it will be [1,5]." - I don't see any relationship between this expected output and the description that precedes it.

Comment: As I mentioned I am beginner so maybe I am doing something wrong . I was interested in if this code can help me , I am trying to write Euler theorem .

Comment: Suggestion: 1) Encapsulate your code in a function `find_coprimes(n)` which takes an integer `n` and returns the list you want; 2) Write a second function `find_coprimes_ref` which does the same thing but uses the standard python function `math.gcd` to make sure it returns the correct answer. 3) test your function `find_coprimes` by comparing it with `find_coprimes_ref`.

Comment: Actually, I think there is an obvious issue with your code: you modify variable `a` in the `while`-loop. This means that after the first iteration of the `for`-loop, the value of `a` has changed. You need to reset the value of `a`. Use a new variable `a_` to store a copy of `a`, and reset `a = a_` at the beginning of every iteration of the `for`-loop.

Comment: `from math import gcd; answer = [x for x in range(n) if gcd(x,n) == 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments about your code:

- You should always encapsulate code like this in a function; write a function `find_coprimes` which takes an argument `n` and returns the list you want;
- In order to test the correctness of your function, write a reference function `find_coprimes_ref` which does the same thing, but uses library functions to make sure there is no error; this will teach you to look for relevant library functions, and you can compare the results of the two functions;
- The initial loop `for i in range(1, len(b)): b[i] = int(b[i])` is wrong for two reasons; 1) It has no effect, as `b` is already a list of integers. 2) Lists are 0-indexed, so a correct iterations on every element of `b` would be `for i in range(0, len(b)):` or simply `for i in range(len(b)):`;
- Your code has two nested loops: a `while`-loop executing repeatedly inside a `for`-loop; whenever there are nested loops like this, you must make sure that variables are reinitialised the way you intend them to at the beginning of the outer loop; in your case, variable `a` is modified inside the `while`-loop, and as a result, its value is wrong at the beginning of the next iteration of the `for`-loop.
- The `break` statement at the end of the `while`-loop makes no sense; in general, `break` statements only make sense if they are encapsulated in an `if` conditional, and they act as a substitute for the loop condition; but it's always possible to write loops without using `break` at all and I recommend you forget about `break` entirely.
- After performing the gcd calculation using `q` and `r`, your code is missing something to tell it whether or not to keep `b[i]` or not in the final result;
- For integer division in python, it is better to use `//` rather than `int(... / ...)`.

### Code

```
import math

def find_coprimes_ref(n):
  return [x for x in range(1,n) if math.gcd(x,n) == 1]

def find_coprimes(n):
  result = []
  for x in range(1, n):
    a = n
    b = x
    r = a % b
    q = a // b
    while (r > 1):
      a = b
      b = r
      q = a // b
      r = a - b * q
    if (r == 1):
      result.append(x)
  return result

# TESTING

for n in range(1, 31):
  coprimes_ref = find_coprimes_ref(n)
  coprimes = find_coprimes(n)
  if coprimes_ref != coprimes:
    print(n, coprimes_ref, coprimes)
```

Note how my code never modifies `n` or `x` in the loop; instead, I make copies called `a` and `b` and modify the copies.

### Encapsulating even further

Note how function `find_coprimes_ref` is so much easier to read than function `find_coprimes`? This is not just because we used library function `math.gcd`. It's because library function `math.gcd` is a cleanly-encapsulated function with a name that explains clearly what it does. Your code contains a while loop inside a for loop and it's a bit hard to keep track of every variable and everything that is going on and not lost track of our sub-objective and overall objective.

To make your function both easier to read, easier to code and easier to debug, You should encapsulate the gcd calculation inside a function called `gcd`:

```py
def gcd(a, b):
  r = a % b
  q = a // b
  while (r > 1):
    a = b
    b = r
    q = a // b
    r = a - b * q
  return r

def find_coprimes(n):
  result = []
  for x in range(1, n):
    if gcd(a, b) == 1:
      result.append(x)
  return result

# TESTING GCD

for b in range(1, 31):
  for a in range(b, 31):
    r1 = math.gcd(a, b)
    r2 = gcd(a, b)
    if r1 != r2:
      print(a, b, r1, r2)

# TESTING FIND_COPRIMES

for n in range(1, 31):
  coprimes_ref = find_coprimes_ref(n)
  coprimes = find_coprimes(n)
  if coprimes_ref != coprimes:
    print(n, coprimes_ref, coprimes)
```

There are two reasons why the code is easier to debug now:

- The logic for `gcd` and for `find_coprimes` is cleanly separated, which means you can reason about `gcd` clearly without any risk of messing up the list and the other variables used in `find_coprimes`;
- You can test separately your function `gcd` and your function `find_coprimes`; and if something doesn't work correctly, you'll know more precisely where to look for the issue rather than just thinking "well, something is wrong somewhere in the code but I have no idea where".

Comment: Note that there is a builtin `divmod` function, so you can replace `q = a // b;  r = a - b * q` by `q, r = divmod(a, b)`. If you just need the remainder, there is the modulo operator: `r = a % b`.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few errors in your code like, `break` inside while loop. I have refactored your code and also added inbuilt `math.gcd` function to compare results.

```
import math

def math_inbuilt_gcd(a, b):
    gcd_one = []
    for x in b:
        if math.gcd(x, a) == 1:
            gcd_one.append(x)
    print("gcd_one_math_fun:", gcd_one)


def gcd_my_fun(a, b):
    gcd_arr = []
    for i in range(len(b)):
        x, y = a, b[i] # taking x, y just to make things clear
        r = x % y # remainder
        q = int(x / y) # quotient

    while(r != 0):
        x = y
        y = r
        q = int(x/y)
        r = x % y

    if y == 1:
        gcd_arr.append(b[i])

    print("gcd_one_my_fun:", gcd_arr)


a = int(input("Enter number: "))
b = list(range(1, a))
print("b:", b)

math_inbuilt_gcd(a, b)
gcd_my_fun(a, b)
```

Output:

```
Enter number: 10
b: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
gcd_one_math_fun: [1, 3, 7, 9]
gcd_one_my_fun: [1, 3, 7, 9]
```